# Trouble loading Zumero module dependencies

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, windows-runtime, zumero

I started out using System.Data.SQLite and "SELECT load_extension("path/to/zumero.dll")", but am currently using the SQLite windows shell because I assumed I was somehow doing it wrong. I get the same error in the shell as I do when I try and load the extension in C# world.

```
sqlite> .load "windows\ext\x64\zumero.dll";
Error: The specified module could not be found.
```

Specifying the absolute path results in the same error message. When I open it using a dependency walker, apparently the following dependencies are missing:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

I feel like I must be doing something wrong here (the dependency on WinRT seems weird) but can't really see what. The "end-game" is having a C# web application on a Win Server 2008 R2 machine that writes data to a Zumero SQLite instance, which gets synchronized to a number of mobile devices.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your problem right away and had the same feeling of "must be doing something wrong" for a while, because I know this was tested on systems as far back as XP.  Turns out it's a problem of backslashes `\` in strings (*ugh*); SQLite uses them for escaping.  Just use forward-slashes `/` instead, or double them `\\`.  I'm going to add an explicit note to the README about that.

I agree that the WinRT dependencies seem weird at first glance.  Looks like they're all ultimately a result of Zumero's dependency on `wininet.dll`.  The WinRT DLLs are way down there underneath system modules like `shell32.dll`.  Interesting how deep in the system they are, though I guess ultimately it's not too surprising.

Comment: I'm still having errors with different slashes - forward, double back, absolute path all resulting in the same error. I've copied the path out of the sqlite shell and done a directory listing with no problem. From the root of the zumero_client_sdk which is the right folder to be using? I'm using Win7-64 bit

Comment: I gave the 32-bit dll a try and it works no trouble - I'm definitely on a 64 bit machine though... Thoughts?

Comment: It's the bit-ness of the code that needs to match.  64-bit Windows can run both 64-bit and 32-bit code, but all the code in a single process has to match.  You must be using a 32-bit SQLite shell, so Windows will only load 32-bit DLLs into that process.  You should be able to verify that the SQLite shell process is 32-bit using Task Manager.  I think on Win7 it puts a `*32` or similar suffix on the process name.  Using a 32-bit shell shouldn't be any problem at all, though you could build yourself a 64-bit one if you really wanted to.

Comment: Since you're building a .NET app, you'll have to be extra careful of bit-ness.  By default .NET apps target "Any CPU", which effectively means their code is 64-bit on 64-bit systems and 32-bit on 32-bit systems, and that affects which extension you need to load.  You'll either need to detect the machine's bit-ness at runtime and load the matching extension, or you'll need to explicitly build your app as x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) rather than "Any CPU".  I'd recommend the latter option unless there's some really compelling reason you need to target "Any CPU" (which there usually isn't).